# ExtJS 4 Set extraParam to the store dynamically

Tags: extjs

I have a combo with a remote store in the modal window. To obtain the data is necessary to send an extra parameter to the store. This parameter is stored as a property of the window. How can I pass it?

This is my app.js file (I use MVC model, atleast try to use it :) ):

```
Ext.application( {
    requires: [
        'Ext.Ajax'
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'PM',
    stores: [
        ...
        'SourceIps',
        ...
    ],
    models: [
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [
        ...
    ],

    init: function() {
    }
} );
```

How I show window:

```
showAddRProbe: function () {
    var data = {
        'deviceId': this.getProbesDeviceCombo().getValue()
    };
    var addProbe = Ext.create( 'PM.view.AddProbe', [true, data] );
    addProbe.show();
}
```

Window:

```
Ext.define( 'PM.view.AddProbe', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    ...
    constructor: function( data ) {
        this.newProbe = data[0];
        this.probeData = data[1];
    ...
```

Required parameter passed as *probeData.data.deviceId*

Combo:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    allowBlank: false,
    blankText: Locale.gettext( 'Please select a Source IP' ),
    fieldLabel: Locale.gettext( 'Source IP' ),
    name: 'sourceIP',
    triggerAction: 'all',

    store: 'SourceIps',
    value: Ext.getStore( 'SourceIps' ).getAt(0).get('id'),
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    queryMode: 'local'
}
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('PM.store.SourceIps', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'PM.model.IdName',

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/getDeviceIps.php'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',

            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
});
```

I tired to add extraParam as follow, but it does not work:

```
var probeData = this.getProbeWindow().probeData.data;
this.getSourceIpCombo().getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam( 'deviceId', probeData.deviceId );
this.getSourceIpCombo().getStore().load();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
  this.getSourceIpCombo().getStore().load({
       params: {
          deviceId : probeData.deviceId
        }
  });
```

Comment: It's work, but with one issue - after I click on the combo it's realod store again without extraParam. How I can fix it?

Comment: Where and how are you loading the store? And why are you reloading it on click? Also I see you have it auto loaded, why?

Comment: 1. 'data/getDeviceIps.php' Nothing special in this .php file, response data is correct.

Comment: i don't mean server side, show the code of where you are actually loading the store.

Comment: 2. I do not add any 'click' listener to this combo, dont know why store is loaded again on first click (only on first click on this combo, after it doesnt load store again).
3. If I remove autoLoad: true value: Ext.getStore( 'SourceIps' ).getAt(0).get('id') doesnt work, not sure why.

About code where I load the store, what exactly I should show? I use only autoLoad: true in store definition and .load() with params with 'afterrender' listener on the window.

I am sorry if I do not understand you correctly or my answer is not meaningful enough. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what else I need to show. Please specify. I cant show whole code - its too large. Everything related to this combo field I have already shown.

Comment: Problem with double load of the store was fixed with using of queryMode: 'local'. Seems now all work just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could add [storeId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-storeId) property to your store and then use

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore');
```

and use this to apply extra params:

```
Ext.apply(store.getProxy().extraParams, {
    foo : 'bar',
    ...
});
```

or

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParam("countriesId", 1) // add parameter 'countriesId' = 1
```

Comment: Issue was solved with using of dbrin advice + queryMode: 'local' for combo. Thanks for your answer aswell, but, to be honest, I do not try your suggestion as it looks very similar to my code in the post.